# geo_ip.js is not working

Tags: javascript, geoip

I am using `"http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"` for multilingual site support but [this link](http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js) is throwing 404 error.

Here is the error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
www.globalenglish.com/:913 Uncaught ReferenceError: geoip_country_code is not defined
chrome-extension://gllmlkidgbagkcikijiljllpdloelocn/contentscript.js:1849 www.globalenglish.com
getuid:1 GET https://api.bizographics.com/v2/getuid?api_key=422935bcbfc445d59f10758c288c…I%252bJLufjW0EE6tV4BHMF43u8yA9qpnPTK8G7tGxJuiy5ReJz%252fscH55wHNbnsJU%253d 403 (Forbidden)
```

[image]

I checked the [site here](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/javascript/) for new link, [this link](http://js.maxmind.com/js/geoip.js) throws 401 error.

I also checked new API [here](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/) but this also did not work for me. JS Link works but `geoip_country_code() is undefined`

[image]

How to make it work again !!!! Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/b8n1btb8/5/)

Thanks

Comment: It seems that this link is not available anymore, and there is an other version of geoip (2.1) available at http://js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js.

Comment: it throws error `geoip_country_code() is undefined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, Maxmind doesn't provide a geoip api through

```
http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js
```

anymore. Although it provides another api as

```
http://js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js
```

However it requires a domain registration etc. according to Maxmind's website. The link below is a clone of the old api and valid for around one year now.

```
http://geoapi123.appspot.com/
```

I've just used this for one of my projects in development stage for a very quick solution. But I strongly suggest you to update your code according to a trustworthy service again.

A working jsfiddle to show how things could play on [here](https://jsfiddle.net/suhaboncukcu/26v3c7p8/); which shows this chunk of code:

```
$.ajax( {
            type: 'GET',
            url: '//geoapi123.appspot.com/',
            dataType: 'script',
            cache: true,
            success: function() {
                var geo = geoip_country_code() + '|' + geoip_region_name() + '|' + geoip_city() + '|' + geoip_latitude() + '|' + geoip_longitude();
                $('#results').html(geo);
            }
        });
```

**UPDATE:**
I realised this answer is still getting attraction. Please be aware it has been years since I wrote this one. The URL I shared does not seem to be working anymore. Also there are much better approaches to handle the problem now.

Comment: Can u share ur code for better understanding ... or may be creating a jsfiddle will be very useful ... thank you so much

Comment: hey @hitesh, sorry for being late with answer. Unfortunately, it seems maxmind doesn't provide api free anymore. Although I'm not sure with buying process this [link](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-precision-services) provides some detail about it. For jsfiddle you can refer to this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/suhaboncukcu/26v3c7p8/) I'm also updating the answer. Please mark as answer if you are pleased with the answer.

Comment: Can I use this for production ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't say that. I think you should find a more reliable source or pay to maxmind for their v2 api.  (Although, I made a research and I've seen this api is working for a year now.)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a message in the console you might have missed :

> Users of the GeoIP2 JavaScript API must register their domains at
>   https://www.maxmind.com/en/javascript_domains

The loading of the library failed because a request is issued to the `js.maxmind.com` domain with your current hostname (`fiddle.jshell.net` in your case) as the referrer to ensure that the client was actually making a request from an authorized hostname.

Comment: Yes, you must register a domain at https://www.maxmind.com/en/javascript_domains ... Or use a free-to-use library, but that is out of the scope of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

hey guys i'm using This script but i don't know why HTTPS doesn't work when i try to redirect .. it only work With HTTPS

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.petabyet.com/geoip",
        success: function(data) {
            switch (data.country_code) {
                case 'DE':
                    window.location.href = "https://google.com/de";
                    break;
               
                
            }
        }
    })

</script>
```